# Expanding window in Polars

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, python-polars

Is there a way to calculate expanding window features(i.e mean,std etc) in polars?
way to calcuate expanding window features in polars.
I found and easy implementation in Pandas but since my entire code base is in polars,I am discoraged to use pandas.

Comment: Welcome please show us your code, input, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They are yet to be added to Polars: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4799

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"B": [0, 1, 2, None, 4]})

df.to_pandas().expanding(3).sum()
```

```
     B
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  3.0
3  3.0
4  7.0
```

You can use the equivalent rolling function with the `window_size` set to the number of rows in the dataframe:

```
(df.with_columns(expanding_sum = 
   pl.col("B").rolling_sum(window_size=df.height, min_periods=3)
)
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬───────────────┐
│ B    ┆ expanding_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64           │
╞══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ null          │
│ 1    ┆ null          │
│ 2    ┆ 3             │
│ null ┆ 3             │
│ 4    ┆ 7             │
└──────┴───────────────┘
```

As this requires knowing `.height` it doesn't work with LazyFrames.

You can get access the same windows with [`.cumulative_eval()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html#polars-expr-cumulative-eval) although it is a more expensive operation.

```
(df.with_columns(expanding_sum = 
   pl.col("B").cumulative_eval(pl.element().sum(), parallel=True)
)
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌──────┬───────────────┐
│ B    ┆ expanding_sum │
│ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64           │
╞══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ 0             │
│ 1    ┆ 1             │
│ 2    ┆ 3             │
│ null ┆ 3             │
│ 4    ┆ 7             │
└──────┴───────────────┘
```